# how to shorten this piece of C# object Oriented code?

Tags: c#, oop, optimization

this is my createcustomer function which returns a customer object to the caller,
getCustomerDetail returns a datatable which then populates the customer object properties with the values. Problem is whenever there's a change in the object, i have to modify this again, how do I solve this problem so that I only need to change in the Customer object and it saves my work of modifying the entire codes?

```
  public Objects.Customer createCustomer()
    {
        DataTable dt = Database.Master.Customer.getCustomerDetail(objCustomer.Custcode);

        objCustomer.Billaddress1 = dt.Rows[0]["Billaddress1"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billaddress2 = dt.Rows[0]["Billaddress2"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billaddress3 = dt.Rows[0]["Billaddress3"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billcontact = dt.Rows[0]["Billcontact"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billfaxno = dt.Rows[0]["Billfaxno"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billpostalcode = dt.Rows[0]["Billpostalcode"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billremarks = dt.Rows[0]["Billremarks"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Billtelno = dt.Rows[0]["Billtelno"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Custcode = dt.Rows[0]["Custcode"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Custname = dt.Rows[0]["Custname"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Doout = dt.Rows[0]["Doout"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Douom = dt.Rows[0]["Douom"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Inuom = dt.Rows[0]["Inuom"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Location = dt.Rows[0]["Location"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Outremarks1 = dt.Rows[0]["Outremarks1"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Outremarks2 = dt.Rows[0]["Outremarks2"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Outremarks3 = dt.Rows[0]["Outremarks3"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Pacout = dt.Rows[0]["Pacout"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Pacuom = dt.Rows[0]["Pacuom"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Perout = dt.Rows[0]["Perout"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Peruom = dt.Rows[0]["Peruom"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shipaddress1 = dt.Rows[0]["Shipaddress1"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shipaddress2 = dt.Rows[0]["Shipaddress2"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shipaddress3 = dt.Rows[0]["Shipaddress3"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shipcontact = dt.Rows[0]["Shipcontact"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shipfaxno = dt.Rows[0]["Shipfaxno"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shippostalcode = dt.Rows[0]["Shippostalcode"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shipremaks = dt.Rows[0]["Shipremaks"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shiptelno = dt.Rows[0]["BilladdresShiptelnos1"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Shortname = dt.Rows[0]["Shortname"].ToString();


        return objCustomer;
    }
```

Comment: Use strongly-typed, automatic `DataSet`s instead?

Comment: err.. can you please explain ?

Comment: Use an ORM like Entity Framework or maybe Dapper? This is probably among the most performant options already, why change it?

Comment: I would use Entity Framework but if you are stuck with datasets you can use http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/StronglyTypedDatasets.aspx (yay google)

Comment: if possible, i wanna prevent using dataset/table.. I am using only dataset/table to display on a gridview.. I am just not familiar how to do this the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Use an Object Relational Model (ORM) tool like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)
- Use a tool like [CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) to automatically generate this code for you
- Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and Reflection to hydrate your object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Auotamapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Objects.Customer>();
var results = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<Objects.Customer>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```